# Ruby shuffle method doesn't work with json parsed array

Tags: ruby, json

I have a json file like this:

```
{
  "data": "12-14.02.2013",
  "uwagi": ["Pierwsza","Druga","Trzecia"],
  "tytul": "Kolokwium 1",
  "przedmiot": "Muzykologia",
  "questions" : [
    {
     "punkty": 2,
     "pytanie" : "Czy lubi Pan reggae?",
     "odpowiedz" : "Tak, bardzo",
     "verbatim" : "if (a){b=5}"
    },
    {
     "punkty": 3,
     "pytanie" : "Czy lubi Pan hip-hop?",
     "odpowiedz" : "Nieszczególnie"
    },
    {
     "punkty": 5,
     "pytanie" : "Czy lubi Pan disco polo?",
     "odpowiedz" : "Nie"
    }]
}
```

and ruby code like this:

```
require 'json'

file = open("pytania.json")
json = file.read

parsed = JSON.parse(json)

questionsArr = parsed["questions"]
questionsArr.shuffle
puts questionsArr
```

questionsArr doesn't get sorted after .shuffle

I tried .sort_by {rand} and shuffling parsed["questions"], with no success.

what's wrong?

Comment: Do you want to *sort* or *shuffle* the array?

Comment: I try to make the array elements order random

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to `shuffle!` the array!

```
require 'json'

file = open("pytania.json")
json = file.read

parsed = JSON.parse(json)

questionsArr = parsed["questions"]
questionsArr.shuffle!
puts questionsArr
```

The method `shuffle` alone will *return a new* shuffled array and will not change the original `questionsArr` array. So you should either use the bang `shuffle!` method that will change the original `questionsArr` array as shown above, or put the result of `shuffle` in a new variable and use it like so:

```
require 'json'

file = open("test.json")
json = file.read

parsed = JSON.parse(json)

questionsArr = parsed["questions"]
shuffledArr = questionsArr.shuffle
puts shuffledArr
```

Comment: it's definitely because of Swift and its exclamation mark meaning, thanks :)

Comment: To elaborate -- `shuffle` is indeed shuffling the array, but it's returning the shuffled array. `shuffle!` shuffles the array and updates it in place as well.